# Remove Spacing in Header and Add Spaces for list in Header

Tags: html, css, spacing

As Picture Shown I need to Add space between the buttons and header title and space between button and content under it. Thank you.

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <div class="intro-lead-in"><strong>The Robot--Personal Lawyer Just For You</strong></div>
            <a href="#get started" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Get Started</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a></p>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="rllbtn">blue   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">14</span></a>

</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/khnjt160/

[image: Space removing and adding]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to add space before the Contact Us section:

```
#contact {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1aanshc/1/

Feel free to edit it according to your preference.

Do you have any other stylesheet that are not included in the fiddle? Nothing suggests that the space under **GET STARTED** should exist, unless I'm missing something. Maybe in your `agency.css`?

Comment: I know. Like I said, I can't comment on the question itself, StackOverflow doesn't allow me yet. I'm more than willing to edit this "answer" though should a fiddle comes up.

Comment: Updated Please check again

Comment: I put the buttons in the header so I can still have that image as my background. I don't need the button list anymore but still need to pt the whole button group up a bit

Comment: @GitaarLAB While I appreciate the explanation, how do you suggest that I talk to @A.Lin? My intention here is to help A.Lin, but maybe even my intention is simply _not_ an excuse to post. Nevertheless, I will update my answer as promised.

Answer (score 0):

add this property to add space between buttons

```
 .rllbtn {
margin-left:5px; /* leaves space between buttons on left */
margin-top:15px; /* leaves space between buttons on top */
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 4px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #44c767), color-stop(1, #5cbf2a));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #44c767 5%, #5cbf2a 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #44c767 5%, #5cbf2a 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #44c767 5%, #5cbf2a 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #44c767 5%, #5cbf2a 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #44c767 5%, #5cbf2a 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#44c767', endColorstr='#5cbf2a',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#44c767;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:7px 44px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

Comment: It works to add space in between buttons thank you but My problem is to remove and add space under and upon the button groups. I just put them into a section and that add space on both top of it and below but how can I remove the space on top of it?

Comment: enclose all button tags within a div. then add css property for the div like margin-top:-5px; or any negative value depends on the space

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in css you get margin from top

> .intro-text {    margin-bottom: 10px;}